# Proving that every integer $\geq 2$ is either a prime or a product of primes by inducting on the well-founded relation "is a proper factor of"

Tags: proof-verification, induction

Gowers mentions in his Mathoverflow answer to the question [Induction vs. Strong Induction](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37944/induction-vs-strong-induction) that the reason strong induction sometimes works better is because the well-founded relation used is not the same as the order type of $\mathbf{N}$. He illustrates his point with the example of showing that every integer $\geq 2$ is either a prime or a product of primes.

Following Gowers's lead, I would like somebody to *check my proof*, which essentially uses well-founded induction on the set $\{2,3,4,\dots\}$, with the ordering "is a proper factor of" imposed on the members of the set. Here it goes:

**Proof**: Consider the ordering $\prec$ given by $a \prec b$ $\iff$ $a$ is a proper factor of $b$. We impose the order relation on $\{2,3,4,\dots\}$. This is a well-founded relation. To see this, note that if $a$ is a proper factor of $b$, then $a < b$. This means that there does not exist an infinite descending chain $\left(a_{n}\right)$ such that $a_{n+1} \prec a_{n}$, because the existence of such a chain would imply the existence of an infinite descending chain of natural numbers ordered by $<$, which we know cannot exist. We now prove that every $n \in \{2,3,4,\dots\}$ is either a prime, or a product of primes using well-founded induction.

It's obvious that $2$ is prime. Now let $n > 2$, and assume that every $k \prec n$ is either a prime or a product of primes. We need to show that $n$ must also be a prime or a product of primes. If $n$ is prime, then we're done. Otherwise, $n$ can be written as $n = ab$, where $a$ and $b$ are both in the set $\{2,3,4,\dots\}$. Furthermore, it is clear that $a \prec n$ and $b \prec n$, so by our induction hypothesis, $a$ and $b$ are both primes or products of primes, whence $n$ must be a product of primes, and we're done.

Comment: Yes, between the first and second paragraph.

Comment: @Marja Although you probably meant it as tongue-in-cheek, I changed my wording to be less idiomatic.

Comment: Both. There is the hole made by the line between the paragraphs, and there is also the proof that $\prec$ is well-founded, which funny enough, would fit right in that space to keep the line of the argument.

Comment: @Marja Filled up the hole.

Comment: @MaxisJaisi This theorem (if you didn't know already) is called the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, and there are many proofs of this - 
one of which is mentioned in the link. [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic